# Store Dependency Graph in SQL Server and create corresponding Graph Object in NHibernate/C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

I basically have 4 days to get something at its basic level working meaning get a graph network object created in NHibernate.  Nothing perfect but just something that can be searched via an HNibernate Graph object (model).

That is, we have data fields (which are gonna essentially be nodes in my object graph) on a web form that when one fieldK for example is updated other fields (FieldB, FieldT, etc.)  are affected (depend on that fieldK ) and also need to be updated in a return as a result of updating fieldK.  This is just one example here, fieldK.

This fieldK we updated could also be in other "trees" of fields (what I think are Graphs in this case).  So if we update FieldA, we need to do a search to see in what other graphs FieldA is in and find it, then traverse its subnodes and update those subnode fields.

So you essentially have a Network of Graphs type of structure.

I've been asked to a) store it in the DB ..in this case being SQL Server 2008 and b) Create an NHibernate object(s) to represent the graph so we can work with it and search and traverse the nodes bidirectional (up and down x trees) and find FieldA and do what we neeed to in terms of updating its dependent fields for example.

So my first thoughts are:

1) Create a table that holds tree structures, for example:

Table: DataFieldTrees

```
DataFieldTreeID     DataFieldID      ParentDataFieldID    Level
---------------     -----------      -----------------    -----
       0                 12                 NULL            0    (Tree1) 
       1                 232                 12             1
       2                 32                  12             1
       3                 100                 12             1
       4                 210                 100            3
       5                 500                 100            3
       6                 600                 32             4
       7                 800                 600            5
       8                 44                 NULL            0     (Tree2)
       9                 400                 44             1
       10                55                  44             1
       11                111                 55             2
       12                211                 55             2
       13                600                 111            3
       14                43                  600            4
       15                15                  600            5

   ....more trees and so on
```

Notice that 600 and 100 nodes are found in both trees for example.

Now I figured ok, I need some way of tying those nodes that are found in multiple trees to their RootTreeIDs so I came up with this bridge table:

Table: DataFieldRootDataField

RootFieldID are those fields in the first table that are the tree roots (rows with NULL)

```
DataFieldID   RootDataFieldID
-----------   --------------- 
    100             0
    100             8
    600             0
    600             8
```

figured this would allow me to quickly figure out which trees a certain node are in for lookup purposes

Finally to mend the graph and make it a graph I created a table to link the graphs (trees) together (relate them):

Table:  DataFieldTreeRelation

```
RootDataFieldID    DataFieldTreeID    RelatedDataFieldTreeID
---------------    ---------------    ----------------------
      8                   800                 15          
...
```

so this would link the first tree to the second (since node 800 in the first tree is connected to Node 15).

I know I'm calling these trees when they are I think sets of "graphs" but I am new to all this and trying to articulate the requirement and my thinking when starting to think how I might do this.

Then there's the whole other issue of creating and parsing this into an NHibernate Network Graph object in C#...and then I have to determine the best way to retrieve this stuff (create linkedLists of nodes, who knows in C# based on what I pull from these tables...no idea yet how I'll do this and form an object that we can search through)

I'm either way off, or have some decent thoughts about maybe how to go about it but not sure if I'm even close to thinking right in terms of how people are dealing with this...

need some help here and/or guidance or reassurance that my ideas make sense.

Comment: So to summarise you want to persist a collection of trees to NHibernate? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Sql server 2008 has a data type called "hierarchy-id". This basically allows you to represent a field and perform queries for hierarchical objects

**The data type:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb677173(v=sql.105).aspx

Quote from the msdn page on how this data type can be used:

- An organizational structure
- A file system
- A set of tasks in a project
- A taxonomy of language terms
- A graph of links between Web pages

Also, this link might be useful:
**How to Model Your Data Hierarchies With SQL Server 2008**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

Comment: why would I want to use that vs. simply creating a table with SomeID and SomeParentID like you would do with categories for example?  (self join table)

Comment: actually I've already looked at what you suggested before posting this stuff.  I'm looking for a graph not just a hierarchy...where you have sets of nodes connected to other sets and including circular references.

Comment: To answer your first question, modelling a schema with existing syntax might make graph traversals a bit (recursive CTEs or cursors afaik) unmaintainable and difficult to debug, while using  inbuilt support for hierarchies gives the advantage of much better performance in terms of queries because the support is inside the database engines. For more information on how to use this as a graph, please refer to:                   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2007/08/17/sql-server-2008-hierarchyid.aspx..I guess you would have already looked at this too, but this is how I would solve it.